# Check whether a string is palindrome or not without using string functions and without using loop statements in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application, string-function

Check whether a string is palindrome or not without using  string functions and without using loop statements in C#. I can do without string functions but i don't know how to check without loop statements. I face this question in one of my interview.

```
using System;
namespace palindrome
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s,revs="";
            Console.WriteLine(" Enter string");
            s = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int i = s.Length-1; i >=0; i--) //**i want to replace this for loop**
            {
                revs += s[i].ToString();
            }
            if (revs == s) // Checking whether string is palindrome or not
            {
                Console.WriteLine("String is Palindrome \n Entered String Was {0} and reverse string is {1}", s, revs);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("String is not Palindrome \n Entered String Was {0} and reverse string is {1}", s, revs);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what do you mean by "without using string functions", but if you're allowed to use `.Length` and `[]`, you can do this with recursion.

Comment: [C++ version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257983/how-to-check-if-string-is-palindrome-without-using-string-functions-in-c)

Comment: did you try any of the given answers?

Answer (score 5):

Willy-nilly you *have to loop* over the string; but you can *hide* the loop, make it *implicit*, e.g.

```
  bool result = Enumerable
    .Range(0, s.Length)
    .All(i => s[i] == s[s.Length - 1 - i]);
```

Sure this solution and alike are close to *cheating*

Comment: you can't just compare `s[i] == s[s.Length - 1 -i]` because a Name can also be a palindrome which starts with a capital letter and ends with a small one. e.g. _Anna_ is a palindrome but your result will be false

Comment: @fubo: if we want to detect *case insensitive* palindromes we have to put `.All(i => char.ToUpper(s[i]) == char.ToUpper(s[s.Length - 1 -i]))` and be ready to *argue*: "we are not allowed to use STRING methods, not CHAR ones" ;)

Comment: @fubo I think we should ignore case for the purposes of answering the question; it's a distraction from the nub of the issue IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Are you allowed to use recursion? Because if so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsPalindrome("ABCDEFG")); // Prints false
        Console.WriteLine(IsPalindrome("ABCDCBA")); // Prints true
    }

    public static bool IsPalindrome(string text)
    {
        return isPalindrome(0, text.Length - 1, text);
    }

    private static bool isPalindrome(int indexOfFirst, int indexOfLast, string text)
    {
        if (indexOfFirst >= indexOfLast)
            return true;

        if (text[indexOfFirst] != text[indexOfLast])
            return false;

        return isPalindrome(indexOfFirst + 1, indexOfLast - 1, text);
    }
}
```

No *loops* there - not even any sneaky little ones hidden in methods that are being called.

Note: I had to assume that `string.Length` and the string array operator are not considered "string functions" for the purposes of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Updated my code. No loops and no string methods. Case sensitivity is being ignored.

> (anna = true, Anna = false)

code:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
bool isPalindrome = s.SequenceEqual(s.Reverse());
```

Comment: i want  without string inbuilt functions.

Comment: @valluriratnlababu no, `Reverse` comes from `System.Linq.Enumerable`  and isn't a string inbuilt function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to say that everyone is technically correct because we all avoided direct use of loops and actual string functions?

However, all the Enumerable extension methods will definitely use loops at some point.  There is no way to avoid using loops when traversing an array.  Unless you know ahead of time how many elements are in the array and you explicitly address each element in that array in code (that will be a lot of code though).

I put together the variations of the answers (with the exception of recursion) and decorated with timers for 1,000,000 iterations.  You will find the timings quite interesting when you run them; I used a console app.

```
        var lWatch = new Stopwatch();

        var s = "ABCDCBA";

        bool result;
        bool isPalindrome;

        ////Simple array element comparison
        lWatch.Restart();

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
            result = Enumerable
                .Range(0, s.Length)
                .All(i => s[i] == s[s.Length - 1 - i]);

        lWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(lWatch.Elapsed);


        ////Sequence reversal and comparison
        lWatch.Restart();

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
            isPalindrome = s.SequenceEqual(s.Reverse());

        lWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(lWatch.Elapsed);


        ////Simple array element comparison; respecting casing
        lWatch.Restart();

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
            result = Enumerable
                .Range(0, s.Length)
                .All(i => char.ToUpper(s[i]) == char.ToUpper(s[s.Length - 1 - i]));

        lWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(lWatch.Elapsed);


        ////Sequence reversal and comparison; respecting casing
        lWatch.Restart();

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++)
            isPalindrome = s.Select(c => char.ToUpper(c)).SequenceEqual(s.Select(c => char.ToUpper(c)).Reverse());

        lWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(lWatch.Elapsed);
```

Do remember the argument about char.ToUpper().